# why Netron render BatchNorm2d layer as bias on my model?

Tags: conv-neural-network

below is my demo code, just to simply show I've written a batch_norm layer, and when I export the corresponding model to onnx file and use Netron to render the network, I found that the BN layer is missing, since I disable the `bias`, I can see the `bias` still exists.

after a few modify of the code I confirm that the `bias` showed in the Netron app is the `BN` because when I delete the `BN` layer and disable `bias`, the `b` section disappled.

the Netron app can render the model I downloaded from internet correctly, so it's can't be the app's problem, but what's wrong in my code?

```
class myModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 20, 3, stride=2, bias=False),
            nn.Conv2d(20, 40, 3, stride=2, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(40),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(1000, 8) # 24x24x3 12x12x20 5x5x40=1000
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)

m = myModel()
torch.onnx.export(m, (torch.ones(1,3,24,24),), 'test.onnx')
```

here is the capture, `BatchNorm` disappeared and `bias` shows
[image]

---

update:
when I delete all conv layers, the batchnorm shows:

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

it's a version specific problem, and if I switch the order bn and relu, it will render the bn layer normally.